# Python: efficient counting number of unique values of a key in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count, unique

There must be a better way of writing this Python code where I have a list of people (people are dictionaries) and I am trying to find the number of unique values of a certain key (in this case the key is called Nationality and I am trying to find the number of unique nationalities in the list of people):

```
no_of_nationalities = []
for p in people:
    no_of_nationalities.append(p['Nationality'])
print 'There are', len(set(no_of_nationalities)), 'nationalities in this list.'
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 11):

A better way is to build the `set` directly from the dictionaries:

```
print len(set(p['Nationality'] for p in people))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `collections` module

```
import collections
....
count = collections.Counter()
for p in people:
    count[p['Nationality']] += 1;
print 'There are', len(count), 'nationalities in this list.'
```

This way you can count each nationality too.

```
print(count.most_common(16))#print 16 most frequent nationalities
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = len(set(p['Nationality'] for p in people))
print 'There are' + str(count) + 'nationalities in this list.'
```

Comment: If I read the original post correctly, `people` is a collection of dictionaries, but not a dictionary itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
len(set(x['Nationality'] for x in p))
```